# splitting polygon in 2 equal parts

Tags: algorithm, polygons

I have convex polygon and I want to get line that is parallel X axis that splits polygon into 2 equal areas. 
I've tried to implement following(for X axis):
0. sort all vertices of polygon in increasing Y coordinate order.
1. get point P with minimal Y coordinate.
2. split polygon by vertical line that goes through P.
3. go through all vertices and add all vertices with x > P.x to q array and all other to p array
4. go through the array of all vertices and look where current vertex belong and on what line it can be projected. 
5. calculate the area of trapezoid I get.

UPDATE: 
I decided to chose 2 vertciex: the most and least Y coordinate and the line given by them 2 divide all vertices in 2 arrays p and q.
Now I need to divide the trapezoid in given proportion. How can I do this if I know bases and height?
How can I split area of trapezoid given by p1 and p2 vertices in given proportions?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Similar to another answer, except with fewer binary search operations, and also this gives an exact answer. Sort the y-coordinates of your vertices. Let m and M be the minimum and maximum y-coordinates. Then start with the middle vertex y-coordinate y0 to see if the line through it gives equal area. If not, then set either m = y0 or M = y0 depending on whether the top or bottom had more area. You will either find a vertex y-coordinate that gives equal area, or you will find two adjacent vertex y-coordinates where one gives the top more area and the other gives the bottom more area.  So you know the correct split is somewhere between these two adjacent y-coordinates. Calculate top and bottom areas symbolically in terms of where the correct splitting line is (you can do this because the range of your splitting line y-coordinates don't overlap any vertices). Then set the two area expressions equal and solve for the correct splitting line. The advantage to this approach is that you get an exact answer and it only takes at most lg(n) binary search operations where n is the number of vertices.

If you triangulate your polygon, you will have at most n triangles, each of whose area can be pre-computed in constant time, and when you slice through triangles with your dividing line and triangulate the resulting regions, this will produce at most O(n) additional triangles, each of whose areas can be computed in constant time. So the binary search part of the algorithm takes O(n log n) time. The final computation (solving for the exact splitting line) takes linear time. So overall time complexity is O(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way this can be done efficiently :-

```
1. A horizontal line cut the convex polygon at exactly two points.
2. You can evaluate for each line segment forming the side of polygon 
   the interval of its y values.
3. Using these intervals you can easily determine the overlapping pairs of lines using sorting.
4. you now have interval of y values (y1,y2) and corresponding lines which are
   intersected within these interval.
5. Consider a pair of line (l1,l2) that are intersected by given y=k where y1<=k<=y2
6. x1 = (k-c1)/m1 and x2 = (k-c2)/m2
7. find difference between the areas of two polygons formed by them is to minimized.
8. minimize F(k) = (A1-A2)^2 = d/dk[(A1-A2)^2] = (A1-A2)*(d/dk(A1)-d/dk(A2)) = 0.
9. as F(K) is only single variable continuous function in interval [y1,y2] you can easily find its solution.
10. The given y=k is minimum for given interval for y.
11. record minimum value of absolute diff for all interval and select the one which is 
    minimum in all intervals.
```

**Time Complexity :-**

```
Finding overlapping intervals is O(nlogn) using sorting.
Finding minimum must take O(intervals*n).
```

**Finding area of polygon using vertices :-**

[Area of polygon using vertices](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea.html)